# PDO to retrieve and display images without creating files

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

Trying to loop through a test database with images (I know many say not to do this, but it simplifies so much in terms of backups, etc.).  I can get the result I want by creating image files on the fly, but there must be a way to do this without creating files.  Can someone suggest a syntax I can use without having to create these image files?

Here is what I have working:

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// query
$sql = "SELECT id,title,author,description,cover FROM books";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();

$q->bindColumn(1, $id);
$q->bindColumn(2, $title);
$q->bindColumn(3, $author);
$q->bindcolumn(4, $description);
$q->bindColumn(5, $cover, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

while($q->fetch())
{
file_put_contents($id.".png",$cover);
  echo ("<img src='".$id.".png'><br />, $title, $author, $description,<br/>");
}
?>
```

I am thinking that we should be able to eliminate the "file_put_contents.." line and in the echo line, replace the

```
<img src='".$id.".png'>"
```

with some php/pdo statement that retrieves the blob and puts it in the proper format. Tried a few things, but have not been successful.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you do not need to do it in 2 separate files and invoke the script in src attribute of img tag.

Try do this

```
echo '<img src="data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';
```

Where $type is the extension of the image(.png/.jpeg/....) and $image is the binary of the image that you have stored in your DB. in my case I pull the value of the type of image from the db, if you store always the same extension(ex jpeg) you can simply write:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';
```

the method is an alternative to do that with 2 files.

Comment: Andrea, this is perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for...so much simpler! thanks a million for helping out the newbie, really appreciate it!

Comment: happy to be useful! This method is more compact and readable, although at the same time more "rude". I am even more glad that work well in your code, because to me on a site I'm working on is driving me crazy, all the 2 method in this post.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write code in 2 files. As when browser gets `<img src="path/to img_file">` code (or code like `<script src="....">`), etc,  a separate request is sent to server by browser at src path value. So, you also need to create file img_file.

Pseudo code is below,

**Firstfile.php**

`<?php
..................... Other code
while($q->fetch())
{
?>
    <img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><br />, 
    <?php 
    echo "$title, $author, $description<br/>";
}
?>`

And at **image.php** file,

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = " ..... where id = '".$_GET['id']."'";

//You need error handling if $_GET['id'] is integer and valid value. I am not writing this error handling code
if($q->row_count!=1){
    //no database row found. It's error.
    echo "Show no image found image. As browser expects image you can not write text here";
    die;
}
//it's valid image, else code is already terminated by above die. 
while($q->fetch())
{
    //show image
     echo $cover;
}
?>
```

I wrote Pseudo code exact code depend on requirements.
If you want .png extension, you can use Apache rewrite. Google it you will get it.
When first time i wrote answer, I missed last php ending tag. By the way, last ending tag **?>** is optional in php.
If you are getting X , it seems first file code is ok. As imag_file is not at server, it's showing 404 error. View source to check whether **$_GET['id']** is correct. If id is correct, then you want to write at file img_file.php

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete code outline with placement of single and double quotes?  I tried replacing the <img src...> code with what you suggested, but it seems to give syntax errors on quotes.  I don't need to use png, jpg is ok too.  How do I use the $_GET in the code placement?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have re-answered it.

Comment: I tried the first part of your solution, but I get a small box with an X in it - the image does not show up properly.  I don't quite understand your first ?> and second <?php - they don't seem to have matching pairs that you normally would find in code... or am I wrong?  If it works for you, there must be something I am missing.  Your further help is much appreciated.

Comment: OH... it seems like I need to use both codes and create a separate file... Ignore my previous comment.  I'll try that again.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Seems to work, but I would have thought there would be a simpler method than this...