# json-encode from mysql return null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, pdo

I am trying to integrate an image with movie titles in my auto-complete text-box.
For this, I have crawled list of movie titles and their poster links (link to the image of movie) in table "film_Posters" of mysql database.

### Question:

Why I get null? Sorry if this question is asked many times, but I really couldn't fix it yet... 
[image: (Please see the image below):]

This is my php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $arr = array();
    try {
        $conn=new PDO('mysql:dbname=imdb;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT movieName, posterLink FROM film_Posters WHERE movieName LIKE :term limit 0, 10');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                  $arr[]=array('value'=>$row['movieName'], 
                               'label'=>$row['movieName'],
                               'icon'=>$row['posterLink']);                    
         } 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

and this is my html/javascript file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<fieldset id = "q27"> <legend class="Q27"></legend>
<label class="question"> What are your favorite movies?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content"> 

<div id="m_scents">
<label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts">
<input type="text" id="m_scnt" size="20" name="q27[]"
value="" placeholder="Enter text" />
</label>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>   

<script type = text/javascript>
(function($){      
  var $title = $('#m_scnt');

  $(function () {
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
  });

  $title.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: testfilmsauto.php,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      $title.val( ui.item.label );
      return false;
    }
  });

  $title.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

    var $li = $('<li>'),
        $img = $('<img>');  

    $img.attr({    //I AM NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART 
      src: <?php echo $rows['posterLink']?>,
      alt: <?php echo $rows['movieName']?>
    });   
    $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
    $li.append('<a href="#">');
    $li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);       
    return $li.appendTo(ul);
  };     
})(jQuery);    
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE:

Here is the updated php file with the answers from @meda and @marc:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    try {
        $conn=new PDO('mysql:dbname=imdb;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT movieName, posterLink FROM film_Posters WHERE movieName LIKE :term limit 0, 10');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }  
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Now, I don't see null message any more, but auto-complete doesn't work at all.. I think the problem is related to javascript part... I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Where does `$arr` (in `json_encode($arr)`) come from in your HTML file?

Comment: @AbraCadaver :)) you are right

Comment: @FelixKling: I defined it in php file.. I am very new to javascript and json so sorry if I have some basic mistakes..

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your fetch loop wrong:

```
    while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

fetchAll() returns **ALL** of the rows as an array of arrays, e.g.

```
$rows = array(
    0 => array( contents of row #1)
    1 => array( contents of row #2)
```

Which means the `while()` loop is utterly pointless. fetchAll will work only ONCE anyways, so there's no point in looping. All you need is

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
echo json_encode($rows);
```

And then in your client-side javascript:

```
 text_to_display = data_from_server[0].movieName;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Sorry, but I didn't understand the javascript part... what is text-to-display? how can I use $rows of php file in javascript? :|

Comment: I mean how can I integrate the movie image with it's title to be shown in the suggest list of auto-complete text box?

Comment: i think that text-to-display is pseudocode, and for use $row inside javascript just open <?php $rows ?>

Comment: @Andrea_86: Thanks for help, but with this answer(Marc answer), I don't know what should I write for img src in javascript file... I used http://jsbin.com/citeyulemo/edit?html,js,output as sample, but I am really confused about what I should do to integrate image with title... :| I hope I could clarify

Comment: like i see in the example link in the src valu you must put the absolute path of the folder with the icons, or not?!

Comment: @Andrea_86: sorry, could you explain more? which folder do you mean? (I have all the image links in my database.. the column "posterLink" which I wrote in the query in my question...

Comment: Sorry guy but in eng i can't explain well as in my mother language, so now i speak in it. @mOna  se il problema è che l'immagine è su db e non riesci a visualizzarla ti rigiro a questo [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431958/pdo-to-retrieve-and-display-images-without-creating-files/22436286#22436286), altrimenti temo di non aver capito.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you need for the pdo Code:

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $rows = array();
    try {
        $conn=new PDO('mysql:dbname=imdb;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT movieName, posterLink 
                FROM film_Posters 
                WHERE movieName LIKE :term limit 0, 10';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

As for the javascript, I don't see any request. You should be performing `POST` or `GET` ajax request, this is way it is null

**jQuery**:

```
(function($){

  var $movie = $('#m_scnt');
  var movies = "";

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'auto.php',
      success: function(response){
        movies = response;
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        $movie.autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: movies,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          $movie.val( ui.item.label );
          return false;
        }
        });

        $movie.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            var $li = $('<li>'),
                $img = $('<img>');


            $img.attr({
              src: 'https://path/to/your/images/' + item.posterLink,
              alt: item.label
            });

            $li.attr('data-value', item.label);
            $li.append('<a href="#">');
            $li.find('a').append($img).append(item.label);    

            return $li.appendTo(ul);
        };
    }
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but now my problem is with javascript part... I am using http://jsbin.com/citeyulemo/edit?html,js,output as a sample, but if you see the link, it defined an array in javascript file.. now I really don't know what should I write in img src part ..

Comment: He is injecting the JSON directly into javascript variable, not via AJAX. Don't know why he is echoing JSON after it is created though.

Comment: @MikeBrant yes very strange I updated  my answer to show how to achieve this. by the way mOna seems to be a she lol

Comment: @MikeBrant: actually I am very new to javascript and json.. So, I just searched to see how I can use php array in js/html file and It was the result of what I have found... So, sorry if I did some basic mistakes... I had no idea.

Comment: @meda: Thanks a lot for your kind support:) I will try it and update you about the result :p

Comment: @meda: Thanks for your great support, but it doesn't work :( I used exactly the same code as you wrote (Just for the img src I wrote only item.posterLink, because "posterLink" column in my table contains the links to images of all movies..

Comment: @mOna [PHP code](http://pastie.org/9666473) and [jQuery COde](http://pastie.org/9666475)

Comment: @meda: I checked both links (PHP code and jQuery code).. sorry, but I didn't get what should I do with PHP code.. because u make the comment the whole code and added some new lines... It seems I am a bit confused :|

Comment: This is because I had to hardcode the JSON in order to test. But of course in your case you would build it from PDO

Comment: @meda: I tested with my code (PDO) and also your code (test code), but didn't work for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63448/discussion-between-meda-and-mona).

Comment: @mOna  I think its because I have not pass the query string, you should hardcode the id just for query string, meet me in the chat